# Loop and Autoplay Video with Pixi.js 5.2.1

Tags: javascript, arrays, video, html5-video, pixi.js

I am trying to implement autoplay and loop on a video (see code below) with Pixi.js@5.2.1 - My question is: bg.baseTexture.source.loop = true; - returns an uncaught TypeError - while the autoplay method works but for some reason the baseTexture.source.loop method does not. Thank you for checking this issue out. Has the most recent version of Pixi.js changed how - baseTexture.source.loop is called? Your comments and help are appreciated!

Here's my code:

````
    createBackgrounds() {

        this.bgArray.map((video) => {

            // create a video texture from a path
            const bg = PIXI.Texture.from(`../assets/video/${video}.mp4`);

            //assigning the texture to baseTexture.source.loop to loop video - and returns uncaught TypeError??
            bg.baseTexture.source.loop = true;

            const videoSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(bg);

            videoSprite.anchor.x = 0.5;
            videoSprite.anchor.y = 0.5;  

            // preload and autoplay video
            videoSprite.preload = 'auto';
            this.autoPlay = videoSprite.autoplay;

            this.imgContainer.addChild(videoSprite);
            this.bgSpriteArray.push(videoSprite);


            // IMAGE
            videoSprite.alpha = this.bgSpriteArray.length === 1 ? 1 : 0;
        });
    }```

``` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'loop' of undefined
    at jello.js:199
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Jello.createBackgrounds (jello.js:194) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

`baseTexture.resource.source.loop` is the answer -- https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/6501 --

Implemented autoplay and video loop:

````
    createBackgrounds() {

        this.bgArray.map((video) => {

            // const bg = PIXI.AnimatedSprite.from(`../assets/video/${video}.mp4`);
            // bg.baseTexture.resource.source.loop = true;
            // // Set image anchor to the center of the image
            // bg.anchor.x = 0.5;
            // bg.anchor.y = 0.5; 

            // bg.loop = true;

            // this.imgContainer.addChild(bg);
            // this.bgSpriteArray.push(bg);

            // // IMAGE
            // bg.alpha = this.bgSpriteArray.length === 1 ? 1 : 0;

            // create a video texture from a path
            const bg = PIXI.Texture.from(`../assets/video/${video}.mp4`);

            // https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/6501 - SOLVED!!
            bg.baseTexture.resource.source.loop = true;

            const videoSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(bg);

            videoSprite.anchor.x = 0.5;
            videoSprite.anchor.y = 0.5;  

            // preload and autoplay video
            videoSprite.preload = 'auto';
            this.autoPlay = videoSprite.autoplay;

            this.imgContainer.addChild(videoSprite);
            this.bgSpriteArray.push(videoSprite);


            // IMAGE
            videoSprite.alpha = this.bgSpriteArray.length === 1 ? 1 : 0;

        });

    }```
````